# Using microfiber to dry my car from water

Tags: water, carwash

I bough this microfiber product to dry my car from water after i wash my car ! [https://www.amazon.com/Sonax-450800-Microfiber-Drying-Cloth/dp/B004PA0G0A](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004PA0G0A) ... but seems the product has 2 different sides. one side with longer microfiber compared to the other side. so which side i should use to dry my car?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, the thicker side has more surface area to absorb fluids faster like a sponge so using that side should work like a sponge. Because it's synthetic, it may not absorb water until its soaked, preferably with  clean soapy water from washing the car. Once its soaked, rinse it in plain water to see how it absorbs then use it to soak up standing water on your car. Wipe and squeeze often. The finer side may work on windows to help wipe off and leave little droplets that should evaporate quickly without leaving streaks. Since its reusable, once done, wash it in soap and water or throw it in the washing machine with laundry to rid it of dirt, grease and oil to renew it for next time.